# Getting error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I am  getting the following error when invoking SOAP Web Services from the client.
Functionality is working, but this error is a problem. I am using Apache CXF-3.2.12.

```
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$AWQThreadFactory$1.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:346)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace
    at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseQName(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:369)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$23.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:817)
    ... 39 more
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:740)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:770)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:766)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$23.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:819)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$23.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:814)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.ListTransducedAccessorImpl.processValue(ListTransducedAccessorImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.ListTransducedAccessorImpl.parse(ListTransducedAccessorImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyLoader.text(LeafPropertyLoader.java:65)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.text(UnmarshallingContext.java:589)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.text(InterningXmlVisitor.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.processText(SAXConnector.java:213)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:176)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:255)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:281)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:127)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:369)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:352)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBUtils.unmarshall(JAXBUtils.java:195)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl$WSDiscoveryProvider.invoke(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:512)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor73.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.performInvocation(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:232)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:85)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:74)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.udp.UDPDestination$MCastListener$2.run(UDPDestination.java:115)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$3.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:421)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$AWQThreadFactory$1.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:346)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace
    at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseQName(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:369)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$23.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:817)
```

I know similar question has been asked by someone in the past and the suggestion their was to remove certain jars. But that was for RESTful Web Services.
Can someone suggest me how to get rid of this problem? This error keeps coming in the logs for every web server request.

**UPDATE**
Initial workaround I did was to edit one of the java class inside one of the CXF jar. I had used downloaded version of CXF that time. But during the final phase of the project, I have moved to maven project using only minimal dependencies required for the project. I do not see the error now. I am using CXF 3.2.13.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace` as you can see this

Comment: Can you please give some more hint where I have to look to resolve the above error. Is it specific to my code (may be an issue with wsdl or xsd?)

Comment: @Ticherhaz My web service is an SPML 1.0 complaint one. I had to add  namespace="##targetNamespace" as follows  <xsd:any namespace="##targetNamespace" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> in xsd file to remove wsdl validation error. Is this anyway related to the current error I am experiencing (web service works fine, but I get error in logs)

Comment: I had looked at the source code for com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.java and found that the exception is coming since NamesapaceContext.getNamespaceURI(prefix) returns null. Since my web service just logs the error, I had commented the exception thrown when the returned value is null. Not sure it has any side effects.